# sqlAlchemy orm insert issues

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

Python version 3.11.5
SQLAlchemy 2.0.20
SQLAlchemy.orm 1.2.10

SQLAlchemy Table definition

```
    class Base(orm.DeclarativeBase):
        def columnString(Length,null=True,primary=False):
            return db.Column(db.String(Length),nullable=null,primary_key=primary)
        def columnInteger(null=False,primary=False):
            return db.Column(db.Integer(),nullable=null,primary_key=primary)
        def columnText(null=False,primary=False):
            return db.Column(db.Text(),nullable=null,primary_key=primary)
        def columnDateTime(null=False,primary=False):
            return db.Column(db.DateTime(),nullable=null,primary_key=primary)


    class XRNetwork(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'xrnetwork'
        rowid = Base.columnInteger(primary=True)
        vlan = Base.columnString(35)
        networkid = Base.columnString(16)
        cidr = Base.columnString(4)
        subnetmask = Base.columnString(16)
        wildcard = Base.columnString(16)
        broadcast = Base.columnString(16)
        netcidr = Base.columnString(20)
        fdqn = Base.columnString(255)
        gateway = Base.columnString(16)
```

this is the function used

```
    def dbInsertData(engine,TableInfo,data):
        conn=dbSessionOpen(engine)
        print(data.items())
        print(*(f'{x}="{y}",' for x,y in data.items()))
        insert = TableInfo(*(f'{x}="{y}",' for x,y in data.items()))
        conn.add(insert)
        dbSessionClose(conn)
```

output from function

```
dict_items([('vlan', '100'), ('networkid', '172.18.104.0'), ('cidr', '26'), ('subnetmask', '255.255.255.192'), ('wildcard', '0.0.0.63'), ('broadcast', '172.18.104.63'), ('netcidr', '172.18.104.0/26'), ('fdqn', 'gateway'), ('gateway', '172.18.104.1')])
vlan="100", networkid="172.18.104.0", cidr="26", subnetmask="255.255.255.192", wildcard="0.0.0.63", broadcast="172.18.104.63", netcidr="172.18.104.0/26", fdqn="gateway", gateway="172.18.104.1",
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Dropbox\_Code_Rework\_Projects\DeviceDB\makeDBsqlalchemy.py", line 93, in <module>
    control.dbInsertData(engine, Table.XRNetwork, XRNetwork)
  File "g:\Dropbox\_Code_Rework\_Projects\DeviceDB\_Modules\_sqlalchemy\sqlalchemycontrol.py", line 34, in dbInsertData
    insert = TableInfo(*(f'{x}="{y}",' for x,y in data.items()))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 10 were given
```

Python version same as above 
SQLAlchemy version same as above
SQLAlchemy.orm version same as above

```
def dbInsertData(engine,TableInfo,data):
    conn=dbSessionOpen(engine)
    print(data.items())
    print(*(f'{x}="{y}",' for x,y in data.items()))
    insert = TableInfo(vlan="100", networkid="172.18.104.0", cidr="26",     subnetmask="255.255.255.192", wildcard="0.0.0.63", broadcast="172.18.104.63", netcidr="172.18.104.0/26", fdqn="gateway", gateway="172.18.104.1",)
    conn.add(insert)
    dbSessionClose(conn)
```

output

```
dict_items([('vlan', '100'), ('networkid', '172.18.104.0'), ('cidr', '26'), ('subnetmask', '255.255.255.192'), ('wildcard', '0.0.0.63'), ('broadcast', '172.18.104.63'), ('netcidr', '172.18.104.0/26'), ('fdqn', 'gateway'), ('gateway', '172.18.104.1')])
vlan="100", networkid="172.18.104.0", cidr="26", subnetmask="255.255.255.192", wildcard="0.0.0.63", broadcast="172.18.104.63", netcidr="172.18.104.0/26", fdqn="gateway", gateway="172.18.104.1",
```

This works so was wondering what im doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ** to unpack a dictionary as key-value parameters. Hope this helps.

```py
insert = TableInfo(**data)
```

Comment: Thanks though i tried that but gues i didnt